# Hitting multiple endpoints in pyspark api

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an API built in python and it's hitting multiple endpoints, but now I have to make a code change now and put it in pyspark. For instance, I hit the authenication, then I do a search, then  I hit another endpoint where I gather some site infor, then I hit my final endpoint where I begin to pull a dataset into pandas. Is it possible to do this exact same thing in pyspark? I've tried doing this with a UDF, but there's a lot of functionality that's missing with pyspark. I then tried to keep the python code in there, but I start to go down a rabbit hole.

Any thoughts on what may be the best practice in solving this?

Comment: Not clear why you need Spark here.

Comment: If you can already successfully do this into a pandas dataframe, you can easily create a spark dataframe with pyspark. `spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer python can handle the user inputs, whereas pyspark can't.

Comment: @Smurphy0000 after I put it into a dataframe in python, I export it to a csv, I'm already going to create a table from that view. I didn't think pyspark "overwirte" would accomplish  this goal.

Comment: python:
arguments = {}
        arguments['--input-file'] = "input"
        arguments['--unique-sheet'] = "bins"
        arguments['--best_matched_name'] = "matched_scores"
        arguments['--final-name'] = "final_results"

        arguments['--experian-useBizSource'] = 'false'
        arguments['--business_group'] = 'Unit Test'

        arguments['--max_ratio'] = 0.5
        arguments['--environment'] = 'test'

Comment: pyspark can indeed accept user supplied arguments... Look at the SparkPi example. My point was that you have nothing to distribute here, and you could use multithreading module in core Python to accomplish the same thing